# Figuring out why capturing by reference in a nested lambda produces a weird result

Tags: c++, lambda

When the outer variable `x` is captured by value

```
return [=](int y){ return x * y; };
```

`foo(2)(3)` produces `6`.

However if I capture `x` by reference

```
return [&](int y){ return x * y; };
```

`foo(2)(3)` produces `9`.

#### Minimal Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    function<function<int(int)>(int)> foo = [](int x)
    {
        return [&](int y) { return x * y; };
    };
    cout << foo(2)(3);
    return 0;
}
```

## Question

I cannot figure out why this happens, can you?

Comment: `x` is local to the outer function. When you call the inner one it's already destroyed. If captured by value it's still alive though. It's pretty much equivalent of returning a reference to a local variable.

Comment: clang-13 hints at the error very well: `warning: address of stack memory associated with parameter 'x' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`x` is local to the outer function, so it's destroyed as soon as that function returns.

Consider a simpler example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int& foo(int x) {
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int& b = foo(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Here it's easier to see that `b` is a dangling reference.

Next we go ahead and instead of returning the reference directly, we return a lambda that captures the variable by reference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

auto foo(int x) {
    return [&x]() {return x;};
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    auto b = foo(5);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem still remains. Once the lambda is returned, `x` has already gone out of scope and is no longer alive. But the lambda holds a (dangling) reference to it.

Answer (score 6):

When the lambda capture `x` by-reference, when the invocation of `foo(2)` ends, the parameter `x` gets destroyed, then the reference captured to it becomes dangling. The dereference on it in the invocation of `foo(2)(3)` leads to UB, anything is possible.

Capture-by-value doesn't have such invalid reference issue.

Comment: OK. Thank you. Changing from `int x`  to either `const int & x` or `int && x` can make the problem gone. :-)

Comment: @user271232 Yes, a temporary will be bound to `const init&` or `int&&`, and the temporary will be destroyed **after** the full expression, i.e. the whole `foo(2)(3);`.